# On GEF, Is it possible to change the Palette's ToolEntry's Tooltip display time

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-gef

I have an editor that uses GEF FlyoutPaletteComposite. The Palette which holds tool entries uses default method to display ToolTip when mouse hover over a tool entry. PalletEditPart is the one that creates ToolTips and it displays the ToolTip for about 4 to 5 seconds (particularly `protected IFigure createToolTip()` method).

I was able to understand the process of displaying ToolTip when mouse over the tool entry, However I am unable to understand how GEF set the display time for ToolTip (i.e when to dispose the ToolTip).

My assumption is that every time mouse over a tool entry there might be method (which I can not seem to find) that create some thing like Display.timerExec(4000millisec, ToolTiip.dispose())).

If anyone knows how GEF palette displays ToolTips and control display time, please give me some hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See org.eclipse.draw2d.ToolTipHelper#displayToolTipNear(IFigure hoverSource, IFigure tip, int eventX, int eventY)
There is Timer created right after the tooltip is displayed to hide the tooltip in 5 secs.

Comment: I found it but yes this is the right answer. Thanks